# setting up a wireguard "relay"

Tags: linux, vpn, routing, wireguard

I have two VPN interfaces, one is my VLAN the other is an internet access. I would like to forward as if it was the default route all the internet traffic coming from the first interface to the latter. But I also want that the host system doesn't use the internet access over VPN, but instead keep connecting directly using the physical interface.

But as far as I know, I should put the default route as the allowed IPs of the VPN interface configuration. And doing this, this also set it as the default route for the host system.

Is it possible to implement what I want? How?